# Centering JQuery is not working right

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I've got a function on Jquery that centers a div containing text, it looks like this:

```
function center_paragraph(){
    var w=$("#paragrah").width();
    var finalw=w/2;
    alert(w+"/2="+finalw); //Test
    $("#paragraph").css({
        'left':'50%',
        'margin-left':-finalw
    });
}
```

My problem is that the method width is returning me a bad value, something like 1000 while the div is around 600. I use this method because the div is on absolute position.

The div css:

```
 #paragraph{
    font-family:'Arial';
    font-size:4em;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    border:solid 1px white;

}
```

I don't do this in the CSS file because each screen can display the text in another size, so I think this is the correct way to calculate the center.

Comment: Change `.width()` to `.outerWidth()`

Comment: Well...is fine. Thanks mate

Comment: you'll also need to append a unit value to your width calculation as well. eg + "px"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should use CSS for this. There is an ideal property for this

```
p {
    text-align: center
}
```

But if you insist on doing it using JS/jQuery, here's the method

```js
var button = document.getElementById("my-button");
var par = document.getElementById("paragraph");
    
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    par.style.textAlign = "center";
});
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">
  This is a paragraph
</p>

<button id="my-button">
  Center Paragraph
</button>
```

jQuery solution

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("p").css({ "text-align": "center" });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="par">
  This is a paragraph
</p>

<button id="my-button">
  Center Paragraph
</button>
```

This would save you the trouble from calculating the width

Comment: javascript style properties are written in camel case - style.textAlign

Comment: Thank you, I've solved it with the simple left/right:0, but it will be useful

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful for you. Don't forget to vote for this post